# GCI.unescape gives <code> tags generation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tags, refinerycms, refinery

```
def coderay(text)
 text.gsub(/\<pre( )?\="" lang="(.+?)">\<code( )?\="" lang="(.+?)">(.+?)\<\/code\>\<\/pre\>/m) do
  lang = $4
  text = CGI.unescapeHTML($5).gsub /\<code( )?\="" lang="(.+?)">|\<\/code\>/, ""
  text = text.gsub('<br />', "\n")
  text = text.gsub(/[\<]([\/])*([A-Za-z0-9])*[\>]/, '')
  text = text.gsub('>', ">")
  text = text.gsub('<', "<")
  text = text.gsub('&#160;', " ")
  text = text.gsub('&', "&")
  CodeRay.scan(text, lang).div(:css => :class)
 end
end
```

The above generates this at the last closing "end":

```
</code(></code(></pre(>
```

Anyone knows why? I am using gems CodeRay 1.1.0 and RedCloth 4.2.9. Ruby version: 2.1.1 and Rails 3.2.19. RefineryCMS 2.1.3 and their blog engine.

I thought that this line was the cure but it is not:

```
text = CGI.unescapeHTML($5).gsub /\<code( )?\="" lang="(.+?)">|\<\/code\>/, ""
```

Edited:

This is in the show.html.erb file:

```
<%= raw (coderay(RedCloth.new(render 'post').to_html)) %>
```

Comment: What’s the value of `text`?

Comment: Im using the blog's wysiwyg editor

Comment: Great. To say what’s wrong with regexp we have to take a look at the input.

Comment: What input and you talking about?

Comment: You are hardly gsubbing `text` variable and yield a garbage. What is `text`?